# Angular 4 Parameterised Path with regex

Tags: angular, parameters, path, angular2-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular 4 Application where my app-routing.module.ts Looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'case', pathMatch: 'full' },                      
  { path: 'case', component: LandingComponent},
  { path: 'attendee', component: AttendeeComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: CaseDetailsComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'summary', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent },
    { path: 'notes', component: NotesComponent },
    { path: 'attach', component: AttachComponent}
  ]}];
```

Right now if there's no match for a route, all requests go to the 
CaseDetailsComponent.
Example:
http://localhost:8080/abcd

Looking at the { path: ':id' , component : CaseDetailsComponent,...}
So the example URL will be:
http:localhost:8080/6748738

Is there a way to restrict the "id" to accept only numbers??

Comment: Why don't you just create a specific path '/cases/:id' ?

Comment: There is an issue about your concerne on github : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12442

Comment: @ibenjelloun: Business requirement. Need to have baseURL followed by Number.